# Check if logged in using Sentinel in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cartalyst-sentinel

Is there a way to check if user is logged in using sentinel::check() in vue file.
I tried using the blade syntax but it doesn't work (see below).

```
 @if(Sentinel::check())
 @endif
```

Maybe anyone knows how?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's blade syntax and you said you're using a .vue file which this will not work. Try posting your Laravel view code and your vue file you want to show if the user is logged in.

Comment: yes that is blade syntax. I wonder if vue has something for checking user if logged in for sentinel. or should i use other way of logging in of user instead of sentinel?

Comment: You can pass it to your vue component as a prop, you could put your component inside the if statement. Without more code, I can't give you a definitive answer to achieve your outcome.